# Date showing same value for ZMI undo tab

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, plone, zope, proxmox

Recently we have updated RAM in our base server and restarted VM running plone 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 operating system. After that we are able to see same date for all transactions available in ZMI undo tab.

We have tried fixing by updating date in VM using following commands

date -s "Thu Oct 20 14:52:46 IST 2016"

hardware clock date

hwclock -w

In catalog dates are saving correctly but facing issue only for ZMI undo. We are not getting any error running plone in foreground mode. Tried googling it and found nothing. Any help solving issue is highly appreciated.

[image]